# 389. Find the Difference LeetCode

Tags: javascript, hashmap

I was solving this problem on Leetcode but I am unable to understand why my solution is wrong I am using the hash map approach to solve this, the time complexity is O(n) but the error is not something related to time exceeding

**Question:**

You are given two strings `s` and `t`.

String `t` is generated by random shuffling string `s` and then add one more letter at a random position.

Return the letter that was added to `t`.

```
Example 1:

Input: s = "abcd", t = "abcde"
Output: "e"
Explanation: 'e' is the letter that was added.
Example 2:

Input: s = "", t = "y"
Output: "y"
 

Constraints:

0 <= s.length <= 1000
```

**my Solution**

```javascript
var findTheDifference = function (s, t) {

    let mapSet = {}
    let final = ""

    s.split('').forEach((elem) => {

        mapSet[elem] === undefined ? mapSet[elem] = 1 : mapSet[elem]++
    })

    t.split('').forEach((elem) => {

        mapSet[elem] === undefined ? mapSet[elem] = 1 : mapSet[elem]--


        if (mapSet[elem] != 0) {
           
            final = elem
        }
    })

    return final
};
```

the Error was for this testcase ->

```
s =
"ymbgaraibkfmvocpizdydugvalagaivdbfsfbepeyccqfepzvtpyxtbadkhmwmoswrcxnargtlswqemafandgkmydtimuzvjwxvlfwlhvkrgcsithaqlcvrihrwqkpjdhgfgreqoxzfvhjzojhghfwbvpfzectwwhexthbsndovxejsntmjihchaotbgcysfdaojkjldprwyrnischrgmtvjcorypvopfmegizfkvudubnejzfqffvgdoxohuinkyygbdzmshvyqyhsozwvlhevfepdvafgkqpkmcsikfyxczcovrmwqxxbnhfzcjjcpgzjjfateajnnvlbwhyppdleahgaypxidkpwmfqwqyofwdqgxhjaxvyrzupfwesmxbjszolgwqvfiozofncbohduqgiswuiyddmwlwubetyaummenkdfptjczxemryuotrrymrfdxtrebpbjtpnuhsbnovhectpjhfhahbqrfbyxggobsweefcwxpqsspyssrmdhuelkkvyjxswjwofngpwfxvknkjviiavorwyfzlnktmfwxkvwkrwdcxjfzikdyswsuxegmhtnxjraqrdchaauazfhtklxsksbhwgjphgbasfnlwqwukprgvihntsyymdrfovaszjywuqygpvjtvlsvvqbvzsmgweiayhlubnbsitvfxawhfmfiatxvqrcwjshvovxknnxnyyfexqycrlyksderlqarqhkxyaqwlwoqcribumrqjtelhwdvaiysgjlvksrfvjlcaiwrirtkkxbwgicyhvakxgdjwnwmubkiazdjkfmotglclqndqjxethoutvjchjbkoasnnfbgrnycucfpeovruguzumgmgddqwjgdvaujhyqsqtoexmnfuluaqbxoofvotvfoiexbnprrxptchmlctzgqtkivsilwgwgvpidpvasurraqfkcmxhdapjrlrnkbklwkrvoaziznlpor"

t =
"qhxepbshlrhoecdaodgpousbzfcqjxulatciapuftffahhlmxbufgjuxstfjvljybfxnenlacmjqoymvamphpxnolwijwcecgwbcjhgdybfffwoygikvoecdggplfohemfypxfsvdrseyhmvkoovxhdvoavsqqbrsqrkqhbtmgwaurgisloqjixfwfvwtszcxwktkwesaxsmhsvlitegrlzkvfqoiiwxbzskzoewbkxtphapavbyvhzvgrrfriddnsrftfowhdanvhjvurhljmpxvpddxmzfgwwpkjrfgqptrmumoemhfpojnxzwlrxkcafvbhlwrapubhveattfifsmiounhqusvhywnxhwrgamgnesxmzliyzisqrwvkiyderyotxhwspqrrkeczjysfujvovsfcfouykcqyjoobfdgnlswfzjmyucaxuaslzwfnetekymrwbvponiaojdqnbmboldvvitamntwnyaeppjaohwkrisrlrgwcjqqgxeqerjrbapfzurcwxhcwzugcgnirkkrxdthtbmdqgvqxilllrsbwjhwqszrjtzyetwubdrlyakzxcveufvhqugyawvkivwonvmrgnchkzdysngqdibhkyboyftxcvvjoggecjsajbuqkjjxfvynrjsnvtfvgpgveycxidhhfauvjovmnbqgoxsafknluyimkczykwdgvqwlvvgdmufxdypwnajkncoynqticfetcdafvtqszuwfmrdggifokwmkgzuxnhncmnsstffqpqbplypapctctfhqpihavligbrutxmmygiyaklqtakdidvnvrjfteazeqmbgklrgrorudayokxptswwkcircwuhcavhdparjfkjypkyxhbgwxbkvpvrtzjaetahmxevmkhdfyidhrdeejapfbafwmdqjqszwnwzgclitdhlnkaiyldwkwwzvhyorgbysyjbxsspnjdewjxbhpsvj"




Output
"j"

Expected
"t"
```

Comment: please ignore console logs

Comment: would be nice if you add the language you used to solve the problem and you can edit your question to remove stuff that you want to be ignored.

Comment: added js tag sir

Comment: _"the error is not something related to time exceeding"_: what _is_ the error?

Comment: i will add it in the post sir ->  basically it was not able to solve a testcase

Comment: I have also removed console logs for better

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your solution failed for `console.log(findTheDifference("ab", "cab"))`. The correct way would be to start with the longer string, `t`. Then use your algorithm, and finally return the letter of the value that is `1`.

```js
var findTheDifference = function(s, t) {

  let mapSet = {}
  let final = ""

  t.split('').forEach((elem) => {
    mapSet[elem] = (mapSet[elem] || 0) + 1
  })

  s.split('').forEach((elem) => {
    mapSet[elem]--
  })

  var result = Object.keys(mapSet).find((elem) => mapSet[elem])
  return result
};

// used to fail for:
console.log(findTheDifference("ab", "cab"))

// test #2: 
s =
"ymbgaraibkfmvocpizdydugvalagaivdbfsfbepeyccqfepzvtpyxtbadkhmwmoswrcxnargtlswqemafandgkmydtimuzvjwxvlfwlhvkrgcsithaqlcvrihrwqkpjdhgfgreqoxzfvhjzojhghfwbvpfzectwwhexthbsndovxejsntmjihchaotbgcysfdaojkjldprwyrnischrgmtvjcorypvopfmegizfkvudubnejzfqffvgdoxohuinkyygbdzmshvyqyhsozwvlhevfepdvafgkqpkmcsikfyxczcovrmwqxxbnhfzcjjcpgzjjfateajnnvlbwhyppdleahgaypxidkpwmfqwqyofwdqgxhjaxvyrzupfwesmxbjszolgwqvfiozofncbohduqgiswuiyddmwlwubetyaummenkdfptjczxemryuotrrymrfdxtrebpbjtpnuhsbnovhectpjhfhahbqrfbyxggobsweefcwxpqsspyssrmdhuelkkvyjxswjwofngpwfxvknkjviiavorwyfzlnktmfwxkvwkrwdcxjfzikdyswsuxegmhtnxjraqrdchaauazfhtklxsksbhwgjphgbasfnlwqwukprgvihntsyymdrfovaszjywuqygpvjtvlsvvqbvzsmgweiayhlubnbsitvfxawhfmfiatxvqrcwjshvovxknnxnyyfexqycrlyksderlqarqhkxyaqwlwoqcribumrqjtelhwdvaiysgjlvksrfvjlcaiwrirtkkxbwgicyhvakxgdjwnwmubkiazdjkfmotglclqndqjxethoutvjchjbkoasnnfbgrnycucfpeovruguzumgmgddqwjgdvaujhyqsqtoexmnfuluaqbxoofvotvfoiexbnprrxptchmlctzgqtkivsilwgwgvpidpvasurraqfkcmxhdapjrlrnkbklwkrvoaziznlpor"

t =
"qhxepbshlrhoecdaodgpousbzfcqjxulatciapuftffahhlmxbufgjuxstfjvljybfxnenlacmjqoymvamphpxnolwijwcecgwbcjhgdybfffwoygikvoecdggplfohemfypxfsvdrseyhmvkoovxhdvoavsqqbrsqrkqhbtmgwaurgisloqjixfwfvwtszcxwktkwesaxsmhsvlitegrlzkvfqoiiwxbzskzoewbkxtphapavbyvhzvgrrfriddnsrftfowhdanvhjvurhljmpxvpddxmzfgwwpkjrfgqptrmumoemhfpojnxzwlrxkcafvbhlwrapubhveattfifsmiounhqusvhywnxhwrgamgnesxmzliyzisqrwvkiyderyotxhwspqrrkeczjysfujvovsfcfouykcqyjoobfdgnlswfzjmyucaxuaslzwfnetekymrwbvponiaojdqnbmboldvvitamntwnyaeppjaohwkrisrlrgwcjqqgxeqerjrbapfzurcwxhcwzugcgnirkkrxdthtbmdqgvqxilllrsbwjhwqszrjtzyetwubdrlyakzxcveufvhqugyawvkivwonvmrgnchkzdysngqdibhkyboyftxcvvjoggecjsajbuqkjjxfvynrjsnvtfvgpgveycxidhhfauvjovmnbqgoxsafknluyimkczykwdgvqwlvvgdmufxdypwnajkncoynqticfetcdafvtqszuwfmrdggifokwmkgzuxnhncmnsstffqpqbplypapctctfhqpihavligbrutxmmygiyaklqtakdidvnvrjfteazeqmbgklrgrorudayokxptswwkcircwuhcavhdparjfkjypkyxhbgwxbkvpvrtzjaetahmxevmkhdfyidhrdeejapfbafwmdqjqszwnwzgclitdhlnkaiyldwkwwzvhyorgbysyjbxsspnjdewjxbhpsvj"

console.log(findTheDifference(s, t))
```

Comment: yeah it worked @IT goldman

Comment: please note even though there are 3 loops here, it is still O(n) = O(3n)